Unable to use ASUS display and Wiseco touch display simultaneously
Edit: I have discovered that, while it wasn't apparent during the installation process, the installation of the AMD graphics card driver failed. I'm not exactly sure why my onboard graphics would produce the particular result below, but regardless this likely changes the nature of my problem. Once I can determine that issue with more clarity, I will likely close this question, and if needed open a new one.
Let's just get this out of the way: I really don't know what piece of hardware, software, etc is the culprit here, so I'm going to provide as much relevant detail as possible. The following are the pieces of hardware I cannot get to cooperate from my Ubuntu environment.

ASUS TUF Gaming VG289Q1A 28" 4K Monitor (with FreeSync) - using DisplayPort
Wisecoco 14.5" 2K Bar Touchscreen Monitor - using HDMI
My PC, including a Radeon 7800xt GPU (if anything else is relevant, please let me know and I will add that info)

I am able to use either one of these displays individually. I am also able to use either of them in conjunction with my old 24" Vizio TV (using HDMI). Additionally, I can use both the ASUS and Wisecoco together, as I would like to, on my wife's Windows PC, which has a GeForce GTX 1080. In addition, I can use the Wisecoco display on my Debian laptop, which has a GeForce RTX 30 Series laptop GPU, without any issue. I have also been able to connect a total of three displays to my own PC (haven't tried 4).
I've tried just about every configuration of ports on my PC to make this work, including having them unplugged on startup. The only thing I can think of is to try using an HDMI cable for my ASUS as well as my Wisecoco, but even if that works it's not sustainable long-term since I'm planning to add a 2nd ASUS and I only have 2 HDMI ports. I'll try it, though, and update once I've tried. I don't know if this is an Ubuntu issue, or an AMD issue, or what. Any information, advice, or other help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: using an HDMI cable for the ASUS display did not fix anything, as expected
I am using Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS, with a Linux 6.8.0-39-generic kernel.

@guiverc Oh, gotcha. I'm new to Ubuntu and relatively new to Linux. I've included my ubuntu and kernel versions, but I'm not 100% certain I've included everything I should. I'm unfamiliar with the term "default kernel stack" and I couldn't ascertain what was meant through a cursory google search. It did prompt me to list my kernel version, though; maybe that's what you were getting at, but either way I guess that it's good to include.

@guiverc Oh, that's right. 24.02 was a mistake. 24.04 is correct. I'll update accordingly.
